# Video stop when on image click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video gallery with thumbnails. when I click on a thumbnail a video shows up. how can I stop/reset video that's playing when I click on another thumbnail?
here is the code I have

```
function changeImage(current) {
    var imagesNumber = 3;

    for (i=1; i<=imagesNumber; i++) {
        if (i == current) {
            document.getElementById("normal" + current).style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("normal" + i).style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r8eboghL/1/

Comment: Your demo isn't of much use without working images and video files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each video an `id`.

Then on the current video about to be shown, use `.currentTime = 0;` to restart to the beginning, then `.play()`.

Also, you can give the 1st video `autoplay` if you want that video to start on page load.

```js
   function changeImage(current) {
     var imagesNumber = 3;

     for (i = 1; i <= imagesNumber; i++) {
       if (i == current) {
         document.getElementById("normal" + current).style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById("video" + current).currentTime = 0;
         document.getElementById("video" + current).play();
       } else {
         document.getElementById("normal" + i).style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("video" + i).pause();
       }

     }
   }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 9pt Verdana;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #EEE;
}
img {
  border: none;
}
#normal2,
#normal3,
#normal4,
#normal5 {
  display: none;
}
#gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
#thumbs {
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
}
#bigimages {
  width: 770px;
  float: left;
}
#thumbs img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
#bigimages video {
  border: 4px solid #555;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 750px;
}
#thumbs a:link,
#thumbs a:visited {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 6px solid #555;
  margin: 6px;
  float: left;
}
#thumbs a:hover {
  border: 6px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="thumbs">
    <a href="javascript: changeImage(1);">
      <img src="Noragami Aragoto Op.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a href="javascript: changeImage(2);">
      <img src="Fairy Tail Op.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a href="javascript: changeImage(3);">
      <img src="God Eater Op.png" alt="" />
    </a>

  </div>

  <div id="bigimages">
    <div id="normal1">
      <video id="video1" controls="controls" autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>

    <div id="normal2">
      <video id="video2" controls="controls">
        <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div id="normal3">
      <video id="video3" controls="controls">
        <source src="http://haignet.co.uk/html5-video-element-test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BG101, after switching to the second slide I can still hear sounds from the movie from the first slide.

Comment: Same, I want the video to stop playing when I click on thumbnail

Comment: sorry... didnt realise as I never have sound on my pc. updated the answer with `.pause()`;

Comment: It works thanks! there is a problem with Firefox where the controls disappear when I click on another image unless I right click, hide controls, show controls. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: not aware of that sorry. could be a candidate for another question.